# Cannot make pimpl

Tags: c++, c++14, pimpl-idiom

I try to make pimpl pattern:

```
//header
#include <memory>

class Table
{
public:
    Table();

private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> *m_impl;
};
//source
#include <vector>
#include "table.hpp"

struct Table::Impl {
    Impl();
};

Table::Table()
    : m_impl { std::make_unique<Impl>() }
{

}
```

But I get an error:

> table.cpp:9: error: cannot convert 'brace-enclosed initializer list' to 'std::unique_ptr*' in initialization : m_impl { std::make_unique() }

I can't understand that I do wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: And I wonder why the compiler error message is so unbelievable unhelpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `m_impl` is a pointer to an `unique_ptr`.

Change

```
std::unique_ptr<Impl> *m_impl;
```

to

```
std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
```